# Vue.js, Vuex vs. Promises

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuex

Imagine, I have a Vue app, required part of which structured like this:

[image]

I have three parts. Where:

**1. Vue part:**

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-if="displayTable" class="dataTable">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        ...
        methods: {
            getDataset: function() {
                this.$store.dispatch('getDataFromDB')
                    .then(() => {
                        if (this.$store.state.dataSet.length > 0) {
                            this.displayTable = true
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
        ...
    }
</script>
```

**2. Vuex part**

```
const actions = {
    ...
    getDataFromDB ({commit}, payload) {
        DataSources.apiGetData(payload.querystring)
            .then(dataset => commit(GET_DATA, {dataset}))
    }
    ...
}
```

**3. axios part**

```
export const DataSources = {
    ...
    return apiGetData (queryString) {
        return axios.get('urlString').then(response => return response.data)
    }
    ...
}
```

**Aim:**

I need to retrieve and save data from DB in store's *actions* and only after that display div.dataTable. And that is Promise's functionality.

**Problem:**

In my case *then()*'s part processing first.
What should I do to fix it?

Comment: This is probably happening because your `getDataFromDB` action doesn't return a Promise. Can you show that code?

Comment: @thanksd The code is shown. Still need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this.$store.dispatch()` call returns a Promise by default, but because you aren't returning anything in the action being dispatched, the Promise resolves immediately and the `then` handler will execute before the async `getDataFromDB` action has finished.

You need to return the Promise created by the call to `DataSources.apiGetData()` in your `getDataFromDB` action:

```
getDataFromDB ({commit}, payload) {
  return DataSources.apiGetData(payload.querystring)
    .then(dataset => commit(GET_DATA, {dataset}))
}
```

This way, the Promise from the action is what is returned by the `dispatch` call, and the `then` handler won't fire until the async action has resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! It's helped!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to handle this would be to have `displayTable` as a computed value, avoiding any issues that may arise from async calls.

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-if="displayTable" class="dataTable">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        ...
        computed: {
            displayTable() {
                return this.$store.state.dataSet.length > 0;
            },
        },
        methods: {
            getDataset: function() {
                this.$store.dispatch('getDataFromDB');
            }
        }
        ...
    }
</script>
```